# Why do we do batch matrix-matrix product?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, seq2seq

I'm following [Pytorch seq2seq tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html) and it`torch.bmm` method is used like below:

```
attn_applied = torch.bmm(attn_weights.unsqueeze(0),
                         encoder_outputs.unsqueeze(0))
```

I understand why we need to multiply attention weight and encoder outputs.

What I don't quite understand is the reason why we need `bmm` method here.
`torch.bmm` document says

> Performs a batch matrix-matrix product of matrices stored in batch1 and batch2.
>
> batch1 and batch2 must be 3-D tensors each containing the same number of matrices.
>
> If batch1 is a (b×n×m) tensor, batch2 is a (b×m×p) tensor, out will be a (b×n×p) tensor.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the seq2seq model, the encoder encodes the input sequences given in as mini-batches. Say for example, the input is `B x S x d` where B is the batch size, S is the maximum sequence length and d is the word embedding dimension. Then the encoder's output is `B x S x h` where h is the hidden state size of the encoder (which is an RNN).

Now while decoding (during training) 
*the input sequences are given one at a time*, so the input is `B x 1 x d` and the decoder produces a tensor of shape `B x 1 x h`. Now to compute the context vector, we need to compare this decoder hidden state with the encoder's encoded states.

So, consider you have two tensors of shape `T1 = B x S x h` and `T2 = B x 1 x h`. So if you can do batch matrix multiplication as follows.

```
out = torch.bmm(T1, T2.transpose(1, 2))
```

Essentially you are multiplying a tensor of shape `B x S x h` with a tensor of shape `B x h x 1` and it will result in `B x S x 1` which is the attention weight for each batch.

Here, the attention weights `B x S x 1` represent a similarity score between the decoder's current hidden state and encoder's all the hidden states. Now you can take the attention weights to multiply with the encoder's hidden state `B x S x h` by transposing first and it will result in a tensor of shape `B x h x 1`. And if you perform squeeze at dim=2, you will get a tensor of shape `B x h` which is your context vector.

This context vector (`B x h`) is usually concatenated to decoder's hidden state (`B x 1 x h`, squeeze dim=1) to predict the next token.

Comment: while you're right about the general implementation of seq2seq, in the tutorial the OP is asking about there's no batch (B=1), so the bmm is redundant - see my answer

Answer (score 3):

The operations depicted in the above figure happens on the `Decoder` side of the Seq2Seq model. Meaning that *encoder outputs*  are already in terms of batches (with *mini-batch size* samples). Consequently, `attn_weights` tensor should also be in batch mode.

Thus, in essence, the first dimension (`zero`th axis in NumPy terminology) of the tensors `attn_weights` and `encoder_outputs` is the **number of samples of mini-batch size**. Thus, we need `torch.bmm` on these two tensors.

Comment: while you're right about the general implementation of seq2seq, in the tutorial the OP is asking about there's no batch (B=1), so the bmm is redundant - see my answer

Answer (score 2):

while @wasiahmad is right about the general implementation of seq2seq, in the mentioned tutorial there's no batch (B=1), and the `bmm` is just over-engineering and can be safely replaced with `matmul` with the exact same model quality and performance. See for yourself, replace this:

```py
        attn_applied = torch.bmm(attn_weights.unsqueeze(0),
                                 encoder_outputs.unsqueeze(0))
        output = torch.cat((embedded[0], attn_applied[0]), 1)
```

with this:

```py
        attn_applied = torch.matmul(attn_weights,
                                 encoder_outputs)
        output = torch.cat((embedded[0], attn_applied), 1)
```

and run the notebook.

---

Also, note that while @wasiahmad talks about the encoder input as `B x S x d`, in pytorch 1.7.0, the [GRU](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html) which is the main engine of the encoder expects an input format of `(seq_len, batch, input_size)` by default. If you want to work with @wasiahmad format, pass the `batch_first = True` flag.